# Identify the last row of a distinct set of data in the field for an Alias ​Column

Tags: mysql, sql, case, greatest-n-per-group

How can i identify the last Row of a distinct set of data in the field for an Alias ​​Column (signaling somehow, with "1" for example).

For this example i need to know, when the ordered `GROUP` "CARS, COLORS, DRINKS, FRUITS" ends.

Check my intended result on this image:

[image]

My base query:

```
SELECT * FROM `MY_DB` ORDER BY `ITEM`, `GROUP` ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter: rows of a SQL table are *unordered*. There is no inherent ordering of rows. For your question to make sense, you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows in each group - I assumed `id`.

Then: in MySQL 8.0, one option uses window functions:

```
select t.*,
    (row_number() over(partition by grp order by id desc) = 1) as last_group_flag
from mytable t
```

In earlier versions, you could use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
    (id = (select max(t1.id) from mytable t1 where t1.grp = t.grp)) as last_group_flag
from mytable t
```

Note: `group` is a language keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name. I used `grp` instead in the query.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. Solution 2) works for me. The Solution 1) didn't work. :(

Comment: @chameleon: welcome. `row_number()` requires MySQL 8.0, so I suppose that you are running an earlier version.

Comment: Server version: 5.7.32 - MySQL Community Server (GPL); Database client version: libmysql - 5.6.43;

Answer (score 0):

You need ordering by `item` column and order by `group column` to find the last record per distinct `group` column.

Use `row_number` as follows:

```
select t.*,
       Case when row_number() over(partition by group
                                   order by item desc) = 1 
            then 1 else 0 end as last_group_flag
from your_table t
```